# "Manually" creating beans with Grails BeanBuilder or Spring GenericGroovyApplicationContext

Tags: spring, grails, spring-groovy-config

I have a class with complicated creation logic (e.g. uses builder).
Back in 2000, because XML is rigid and not a programming language, I couldn't code the creation logic in it, so I encapsulated it in a FactoryBean.

Then the blessed JavaConfig came (thank you, @cbeams) and threw FactoryBean to the dumpster of history.

Since GroovyConfig is an additional step forward (not only a true programming language for the configuration, but also with DSL), I was sure to find a simple and elegant way to code my way though complicated creation logic, but didn't find any mention of an ability to do so?!

I understand that GroovyConfig is more or less taken verbatim from Grails BeanBuilder, so maybe if there is a way to do it there it will also work in GroovyConfig (fingers crossed).

Please tell me I am missing something obvious and don't have to use FactoryBean again!

Sleeping on it, I think the answer is no. I am adding an answer (still hoping it will get horribly downvoted as wrong one). Please prove me wrong!

Comment: I don't get the hating on `FactoryBean` - it's a 3-method interface, `Object getObject()`, `Class getObjectType()`, and `boolean isSingleton()`. Pretty much what you'd expect - what did you create, what type should it be worked with as, and will there be just this one, or should we expect more. Perhaps you had an awkward experience with a `FactoryBean`, things got a little wild, there was too much alcohol, then some inappropriate touching, and then some stuff you'd rather not talk about. That's cool, but it was years ago, and `FactoryBean` is sorry, and has grown personally a lot since then.

Comment: Hahaha, great one :) On a serious note, I don't hate the FactoryBean itself, I hate XML that forces me to use redundant entity.

Comment: groovy question w/o a single line of code?! OMG! :)

Comment: Scratching my head on where to sneak some code. Nope, just theory about Spring internals. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about it, it looks like the answer is "no". It looks like I can't manage without `FactoryBean`, that's why:

- XML and GroovyConfig are `BeanDefinitionReader`s. They are parsing the config files (XML and groovy script respectively) and creating `BeanDefinition` out of them. Whatever logic I code in the groovy script effects the BeanDefinition (e.g. I can wrap scope in `if-else`). Then, *in later phase* which I don't have the control of, Spring creates the bean objects based on the definition *by itself*.
- JavaConfig is different. It's not parsed as a config file for `BeanDefinition` creation, but instead the objects created in it are *the beans themselves* (and the `BeanDefinition`s with them)! Which means that I have control in the time of bean creation and can implement any bean instance creation logic without `FactoryBean`, not only `BeanDefinition` logic.

Comment: What I really need is a bean creation time callback. I might end up doing that.